# Finding the lower bounds of an algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

I am struggling to calculate the lower bounds of an algorithm. What is the right way to proceed.

For eg, I have the following algorithm

```
For i=1, 2,...,n
    For j=i+1, i+2,...,n
        Add up array entries A[i] through A[j]
    Store the result in B[i, j] Endfor
Endfor
```

How do I calculate the lower bounds of this algorithm

Comment: Lower bound of what? Of the running time of your algorithm in terms of the length of the input? I guess you mean a non-trivial one. For the above example you can get easily a tight bound. Otherwise you try to bound everything from below as good as you can.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The complexity is proportional to the number of reads from the array $A$.

Comment: Asymptotically, that is.